# Examples of use cases for _.result

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

As soon as I read the [docs for underscore.js' _.result](http://underscorejs.org/#result) I thought it might be useful in the context of form validation.  So in my backbone view I have a save method as follows:

```
save : function() {
    var values = _.reduce(this.$el.find(":input"), function(values, input) {
        values[input.name] = input.value;
        return values;
    }, {});

    this.showErrors(_.result(this.validate(values), 'unlessValid'));

    /*
    NOTE: I've concluded this is a more idiomatic underscore.js approach

    _.compose(submitForm, _.wrap(unlessFormInvalid, showFormErrors));

    However I've left out 'this.' to reduce the 'noise', and yet the calls
    to '_.compose' and '_.wrap' make this noisier than I'd like anyway, and 
    would undoubtedly be exacerbated in cases where there are more than just
    'unless' and (implicit above) 'if' conditions.  Therefore I'm becoming more
    inclined to implement my own sort of promise/'thennable' interface, such as:

    this.validateForm().then({
        onValid: this.submitForm,
        onInvalid: this.showFormErrors
    });
    */
}
```

I feel as though the final line nicely describes the process.  However my implementation seems like a bit of overkill, because I always only return an object with one property: 'unlessValid'.  Below is the complete "pipeline" of other methods, and they work as expected.  However I'd be curious as to other possibly better examples of use cases for underscore.js' _.result functionality.

```
submissionErrors : function(values) {
    console.log('inside submissionErrors -- always get here');
    console.log('but only reach showErrors if submissionErrors returns value');
   // return {};
},

validate : function(values) {
    var unlessValid = this.submissionErrors(values) || this.persist.call(this, values);

    return {
        unlessValid: unlessValid
    }
},

persist : function(values) {
    console.log('inside persist');
},

showErrors : function(errors) {
    if (errors) {
        console.log('inside show Errors');
    }
}
```

Comment: backbone itself uses `.result`.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this (and down-modded it) because this is supposedly primarily opinion based, you would be wrong.  I've asked for examples of other use cases, "possibly better", but any examples.

Comment: I don't think your code is benefiting from `_.result`; it would behave the same if you had just `this.showErrors(this.validate(values));`, and `validate` simply returned `this.submissionErrors(values) || this.persist.call(this, values);`. You seem to never return a function in `unlessValid`...

Comment: This question is *not* about my code: it's obvious I myself question whether I'm benefiting from _.result.  I'm seeking other examples of _.result's usage so I can get other ideas for when it might be more useful to use it.  But you seem right, I could change unlessValid to return _.bind(this.persist, this) and then it would return a function as long as submissionErrors returned no value

Comment: Yet another vote to close supposedly for being opinion based, which it isn't; I even made an effort to word it so it wasn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_.result` has a very simple purpose (as with most functions in underscore). It lets you get a named value from an object without knowing or caring whether that value is stored as a property or a method. Thus:

```
var nameProperty = {name: 'Peter'};
var nameMethod = {name: function () {return 'Peter';}};
console.log(_.result(nameProperty, 'name'));
console.log(_.result(nameMethod, 'name'))
```

In both cases, the code will work, successfully log the name and not throw a `TypeError`.

That's really all it's for. It's pretty simple and clear.

Real world example would be `Backbone.Model.url`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.  Why I thought it could be nice in terms of form validation is, typically you either want to do something with the result of your form validation, if there are errors for instance, or you want to execute a function.  Just trying to push my knowledge of underscore, but in my case possibly simply passing a callback would be cleaner.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty That might in fact be a use case. In Modern JavaScript normally [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) serve this purpose and stuff like `_.result` is no longer required.

Comment: The underscore documentation was succinct enough that I thought there had to be more to it. Thank you for the explanation.